# How can I install a full vent for my clothes dryer?

Tags: dryer, vent, hose

I purchased an older home and the dryer vent connection is just a hole in the floor with a torn flexible hose. I would like to repair this, to code, as cheaply as I can. The hole in the ceramic tile floor is 4".

Will I have to go into the crawl space under the home to install a new hose? Or should I use a rigid aluminum pipe? I am guessing I could stick a metal collar like thing into the floor and seal any gaps with silicone caulking. Attach the dryer to the collar then crawl beneath the house and use metal straps to hang the pipe?

Please keep in mind I am an old woman and am a chicken lol. What type of person usually handles this i.e. handyman, plumber? Advice would be appreciated. I am thinking of contacting my local Lowe's home improvement to see if they do this but I really don't want to pay $200.00 or above when I can supply the necessary parts. Thanks for your time and I wish you the best!

Update: The dryer is electric. The existing damaged flex hose extends approximately 17' to the nearest exterior wall, where an exit vent used to be located, now it's just an open hole without a cover. I believe I need a roll of foil tape as I'm going to be using rigid metal pipe instead of full flex hose, so I don't have to worry about the possibility of fire. Thank goodness the crawl space is lighted as I recently had it sealed to code. Thank you all again I truly appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Is there an outside wall near the dryer? Is the dryer gas or electric?

Comment: What is the distance from the dryer to the nearest convenient exterior wall?

Comment: A good handyman will improve your life. Ask your neighbors for recommendations.

Comment: And, for what it’s worth, there are so many variables in a job like this that it could be a couple hundred or (worst case) a couple thousand. (Worst case is booster fan, new electrical circuit, permit, coring the foundation, etc.)

Comment: You definitely want to replace your flexible hose. For the fixed straight stretches, use aluminum or galvanized 4" vent pipe. For other stretches, I use "semi-rigid" aluminum 4" ducting. Once you've stretched it out, it's almost impossible to unstretch it, so start small and only expand parts as needed.

Comment: The only problem with using an unknown handyman for work in a crawl space (or attic) that he knows you won't go into is that he can take a lot of shortcuts and do a poor job that won't be apparent until, for example, you start seeing lint in your crawl space.

Comment: And like Armand said, I would only use 4" aluminum, making sure the male/female go together in the right direction, and fasten the joints with aluminum tape, not screws.

Answer (score 4):

We are all chicken crawling in the tight dark places. You newer know who lives there and call it its home.
Some eight legged creature, some 4 legged creatures, some no legs creature...who knows !

Yes, using rigid Al pipe would be the best, that will also prevent the dryer lint from clogging.

A handyman can do that job.

Depending where you live a handyman will cost you $200 for 4 hours work, which this is.

Comment: this is HVAC work, but the HVAC professionals may not be interested in such a small job, so handyman is a good call.   (HVAC  = heating ventilation and air conditioning)

Comment: Rigid dryer ducting will help reduce the amount of lint clog, but won't completely eliminate it.  Rigid dryer ducts still need occasional cleaning to remove lint buildup.

Comment: A's list and others are pay-for-placement lists, so basically advertising like the Yellow Pages used to be. I would try recommendations first as suggested, then maybe someplace like a senior center (ours has a list of at least semi-vetted tradespeople).